# Creating file with non english characters in the file name

Tags: java, file, io, internationalization, chinese-locale

How to create a file with chinese character in file name in Java? I have read many stack overflow answers but couldn't find a proper solution. The code I have written till now is as follows:

```
private void writeFile(String fileContent) {
try{
    File file=new File("C:/temp/你好.docx");
        if(file.exists()){
            file.delete();
        }
        file.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        fos.write(fileContent);
        fos.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The file is written to the output directory but the name of the file contains some garbage value. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Chinese characters exist in Unicode, so it's not obvious why this wouldn't work. Can you post a code sample of what you've tried, maybe with an exception log? Which platform (Win/Mac/Unix) and file system (NTFS/ext3/JFS) is giving you trouble?

Comment: There are no exceptions. The file is created but with  random filename. I am working with Windows 7 (NTFS) and JDK 6.

Comment: Well I downvoted and was typing up a comment asking for code, and you added it while I was typing. You need to use Unicode escape sequences: `\uNNNN` for that name. I am not familiar with those characters but I suspect you are migrating into UTF-32 territory.

Comment: Thanks for your reply John. I will actually get the filename in any language and not just Chinese. I have to make sure that the name of the written file is same as the given file which would later be read as a function parameter. Would utf-8 encoding be enough to support common languages? Also do I need to escape every character of the file name by appending \uNNNN in front of it?

Comment: there are tools to help you transform a text file to those utf escape sequence.  e.g. JDK contains native2ascii .  It should work good if you put those string literals in a separate resource text file and process it using native2ascii.  Anyway, embedding in source code should still work but make sure that the char encoding you used in compilation and saving the file is the same.  Recommended to use UTF-8 for both

Answer (score 0):

I believe the key is as what I have mentioned in the comment.

You can have Chinese characters (or other non-ascii character) as literals in source code.  However you should make sure two things:

1. The encoding you use to save the source file is capable to represent those character (My suggestion is just to stick with UTF-8)
2. The `-encoding` parameter you passed to `javac` should match the encoding of the file.
   For example, if you use UTF-8, your javac command should looks like

   `javac -encoding utf-8 Foo.java`

I have just tried a similar piece of code you have, and it works well in my machine.